# cURL Commandline to php version

Tags: php, curl

when I use the following on command line I am getting the output perfectly.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: sso-key API_KEY:API_SECRET" "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/mydomain.com"
```

but when I try to get this from PHP using the following code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ "Authorization: sso-key API_KEY:API_SECRET"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "API_KEY:API_SECRET");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

I failed to get anything.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Try to `print curl_error($ch);` to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$URL = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/mydomain.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ "Authorization:  sso-key API_KEY:API_SECRET"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
var_dump($result);
var_dump($httpCode);

curl_close ($ch);
```